# cannot initialize a variable of type 'jstring' (aka '_jstring *') with an rvalue of type 'jobject' (aka '_jobject *')

Tags: android, android-ndk

Does anyone know how to solve the error?

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL JAVA_com_pfc_camera_ndkmain_MainActivity_compresion(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jobjectArray jargv){



//jargv is a Java array of Java strings
    int argc = env->GetArrayLength(jargv);
    typedef char *pchar;
    pchar *argv = new pchar[argc];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        jstring js = env->GetObjectArrayElement(jargv, i); //A Java string
        const char *pjc = env->GetStringUTFChars(js); //A pointer to a Java-managed char buffer
        size_t jslen = strlen(pjc);
        argv[i] = new char[jslen+1]; //Extra char for the terminating null
        strcpy(argv[i], pjc); //Copy to *our* buffer. We could omit that, but IMHO this is cleaner. Also, const correctness.
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(js, pjc);
    }

    //Call main
    Principal *pa=Principal::CreateInstance(argc,argv);
    pa->Run();
    pa->FreeInstance();

    //Now free the array
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
        delete [] argv[i];
    delete [] argv;
```

}

I understand that the error can come from not doing a casting but I do not have it very clear

[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOWKZ.png][1]

It seems that the problem has been solved, now I get another error but I do not understand if I'm passing two arguments js and pjc

[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHCAR.png][1]

Comment: Could you give me an example? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you have to use explicit conversion to your desired type.

```
jstring js = (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement(jargv, i);
```

You can learn about jni programming [`here`](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/cpp.html)

Regarding your other question do the following:

```
const jbyte *pjc = env->GetStringUTFChars(js, NULL);
```

Comment: It seems that the problem has been solved, now I get another error but I do not understand if I'm passing two arguments js and pjc